# SPI in PostgreSQL C function causing loss of connection (Windows)

Tags: c, postgresql

I'm developing a C function for PostgreSQL but I’m facing some problems. Here's a simplified example where I try to connect via SPI:

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include "catalog/pg_type.h"
#include "utils/builtins.h"
#include "utils/numeric.h"
#include "executor/spi.h"

PG_MODULE_MAGIC; 

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(add_one); 

PGDLLEXPORT Datum add_one(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);

Datum add_one(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
    int32 arg = PG_GETARG_INT32(0);
    SPI_connect();    
    SPI_finish();
    PG_RETURN_INT32(arg + 1);
}
```

I created a DLL project in Dev-C++, set include paths, library path and linked with postgresql.lib, according to https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Building_and_Installing_PostgreSQL_Extension_Modules (Building with a Visual Studio project file).
Then I compiled it and put the DLL into PostgreSQL lib folder. Also, I was able to create the function in my database using this command:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo(integer) RETURNS integer AS '$libdir/example1', 'add_one' LANGUAGE C STRICT;
```

So far, everything's good. However, when I try to execute a select in PgAdmin3 (e.g. `SELECT foo(1)`), a message appears saying the connection to the database was lost and asks “Do you want to attempt to reconnect to the database?”.
The thing is, when I remove `SPI_connect()` and `SPI_finish()` from my code, it works.

I'm using a Windows 7 x64 with PostgreSQL v9.2.18 x64.

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I've removed the *spi* tag as it is for *Serial Peripheral Interface* (and not for PostgreSQL's *Server Programming Interface*).

Comment: Your function works fine on my Linux system, so there's probably something wrong with your build process. You should [get a stack trace](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Getting_a_stack_trace_of_a_running_PostgreSQL_backend_on_Windows)  and determine where PostgreSQL is crashing.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'll try to get it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite some time working on this, I finally solved it.

According to [PostgreSQL Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/install-windows-full.html), the version I use could be built with Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2012 (including Express editions).

So, I've downloaded the 2012 Express edition and followed [these instructions](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/compiling-postgresql-extensions-visual-studio-windows/) by Craig Ringer before getting a stack trace (as was suggested by Laurenz Albe).

The DLL generated by VS 2012 is working fine. Apparently, there's something to do with Dev-C++'s build method.